# Faceting in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following head of a  dataframe that I want to facet by actings_corps_descriptions and create grouped bar plots.

How can I do this in R so that I'll get 2 columns and 5 rows. There are 10 distinct acting_corps_descriptions in my dataset, but I just provide 2 here.

```
   actings_corps_description ropple_bucket pos_bucket     n  freq
   <chr>                     <chr>         <chr>      <int> <dbl>
 1 BOC-Gerrink               0-200         0-25          54 0.931
 2 BOC-Gerrink               0-200         26-50        368 0.906
 3 BOC-Gerrink               0-200         51-75        266 0.989
 4 BOC-Gerrink               0-200         75+           13 1    
 5 BOC-Gerrink               201-400       0-25           3 0.052
 6 BOC-Gerrink               201-400       26-50         33 0.081
 7 BOC-Gerrink               201-400       51-75          3 0.011
 8 BOC-Gerrink               401-600       0-25           1 0.017
 9 BOC-Gerrink               401-600       26-50          5 0.012
10 KND-Initial AB Issues     0-200         0-25         290 0.871
11 KND-Initial AB Issues     0-200         26-50       2840 0.884
12 KND-Initial AB Issues     0-200         51-75       1561 0.982
13 KND-Initial AB Issues     0-200         75+           16 0.889
14 KND-Initial AB Issues     201-400       0-25          35 0.105
15 KND-Initial AB Issues     201-400       26-50        342 0.106
16 KND-Initial AB Issues     201-400       51-75         28 0.018
17 KND-Initial AB Issues     201-400       75+            2 0.111
18 KND-Initial AB Issues     401-600       0-25           8 0.024
19 KND-Initial AB Issues     401-600       26-50         31 0.01 
20 KND-Initial AB Issues     600+          26-50          1 0
```

I have the following code here for just 1 of the actings_corps_descriptions:

```
final_res %>%
  dplyr::filter(actings_corps_description == "BOC-Gerrink") %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(fill = ropple_bucket, x = pos_bucket , y = n)) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  ggplot2::geom_text(ggplot2::aes(label = freq),
                     position = ggplot2::position_dodge(width = 0.9),
                     size = 2.5, family = 'sans', fontface = 'bold') +
  ggplot2::ggtitle('Relationship between Position and Ropple') +
  ggplot2::labs(y = 'n', x = 'Average Position Bucket') + 
  ggplot2::guides(fill = ggplot2::guide_legend(title='Ropple Bucket'))
```

Comment: Remove the `filter` line and add `+ facet_wrap(.~actings_corps_description, nrow = 5)` to your plot call.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the practical implementation of @Allan Cameron's suggestions:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = ropple_bucket, x = pos_bucket , y = n)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(. ~ actings_corps_description, scales = "free_y", ncol = 2, nrow = 5)+
  geom_text(aes(label = freq), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust=-1,
            size = 2.5, family = 'sans', fontface = 'bold') +
  ggtitle('Relationship between Position and Ropple') +
  labs(y = 'n', x = 'Average Position Bucket') + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title='Ropple Bucket'))
```

[image]